# Service Advertice and Class Usage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When we try to advertise a service we normally use as shown in ros tutorials:

```
 ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", add);
```

This is with normal function way.

And if we want to use with class, documentation says use like this:

```
AddTwo a;
 ros::ServiceServer ss = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &AddTwo::add, &a);
```

Which means we need to initialize an object first.

But suppose I want to use everything related with ros in class and suppose my code is like this:

```
Comm::Comm()
{
  ros::ServiceServer ss = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", &write);
  // write() is member of Comm class.
}
```

In my mind, I should have been use like this, but of course this kind of usage gave me error. Is there any possibility to use service advertise in class as describe. Do I need to initialize the class always?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43172/service-advertice-and-class-usage/) by [cheour](https://answers.ros.org/users/2230/cheour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use it the same way as above with: `&Comm::write, this`.

Also you might want to store the ServiceServer as a member variable as otherwise it will go out of scope.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1